# Installing ejabberd in ec2 linux instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I'm creating an instant messaging iOS app using XMPP ejabberd server.it works fine in local host.But im stuck in installing ejabberd in ec2 linux instance.
I'm following steps from this page ->[click here](http://www.sebastianhaas.at/installung-running-ejabberd-aws-ec2-instance/)

But im getting an error at the end of installation as

> Installing
>    0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
>    ########################################
>   Error: Error running Post Install Script.
>   The installation may have not completed correctly
>   Press [Enter] to continue:

also when im starting  it using the command

> sudo /opt/ejabberd-13.12/bin/ejabberdctl start  and sudo /opt/ejabberd-13.12/bin/ejabberdctl statusckquote

its starting ejabberd in my local host.The response is

> The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
>   ejabberd 17.04 is running in that node

Please help me if anyone had done this before.
thank you

Comment: have you posted the full error log from installation ?

Comment: i tried and now its installed perfectly...but now when im starting it,it is starting my ejabberd@localhost@deimus